# SSRS aggregate data for days and for month within the same table

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, report, tabular

Supposing the following dataset:
*- product 
- date 
- producedUnit*

How can I realize the following tale:

*Product | sum of Produced Unit this day | sum of produced Unit this Month*

I don't want group record so if in the dataset there are 10 product I want to display them all.

As example:
Input dataset:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+
|Product | date        | produced unit |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| M&Ms   | 2018-02-08  |       5       |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| M&Ms   | 2018-02-08  |       2       |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| M&Ms   | 2018-02-28  |       3       |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| Kit Kat| 2018-02-08  |       10      |
+--------+-------------+---------------+
| Kit Kat| 2018-02-28  |       10      |
+--------+-------------+---------------+

Today is 2018-02-08
Output:
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Product | sum of Produced Unit this day | sum of produced Unit this Month |
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| M&Ms   |             7                 |                10               |
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| M&Ms   |             7                 |                10               |
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| M&Ms   |             7                 |                10               |
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Kit Kat |            10                 |                20               |
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Kit Kat |            10                 |                20               |
+--------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Column headings are a good start but I prefer some data to go along with them too to add substance to the example.

Comment: Have you tried grouping by Product (so you have one row per Product) as well as Day/Month and then sum the units?

Comment: I don't want to make a group by because I'll have further attributes univocal for the record but I need every time the given informations.

Comment: You will still a row group, even if that group is grouped by everything except the date, then you'll need a column group, grouped by date and that should be it.

Comment: I would do that in the Stored Proc

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a calculated field to your Dataset that gets the Month of the production date. For this example, I used `=Month(Fields!Date.Value)`, but if you are crossing years, you may need to use the first day of each month as your common value.
2. Add a calculated field to get the number produced today. For example:
   `=IIf(Fields!Date.Value = "2/8/2018", Fields!Produced.Value, Nothing)`
3. Create a new Table. Change the "Details" group to be grouped by Month. Add a parent row group that is grouped by Product.
4. The expression for "sum of Produced Unit this day" would be like this:
   `=Sum(Fields!Produced_Today.Value)`
5. The expression for "sum of produced Unit this Month" would be like this:
   `=Sum(Fields!Produced.Value)`
6. Here's a sample of the result:
   [image]

Explanation: The table first groups by Product and then by month. You could hide the month and date columns if you don't want to show those. The amount produced today is being filtered at the Dataset level. The amount produced this month is being summed within the scope of the Month group.

Obviously, this is a trivial example, but you can take the principles shown here to account for more variables such as multiple months in your dataset.